# Trying to add a Hyperlink Formula using VBA and a Variable

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, hyperlink

I know how to add a formula to a worksheet that my macro is looping through

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Formula = "=1+1"
```

and I know how to set up a Hyperlink Formula if I know the sheet name

> =HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!A1","Sheet2")

but im having some trouble combining the two,

I have the Sheet name stored in a Variable (Sheet_Name) and im trying to set up the Hyperlink Formula to contain that (So instead of #Sheet2 I want it to use the Sheet_Name variable instead)

I cant seem to get the syntax to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""#'" & sheet_Name & "'!A1"",""" & sheet_Name & """)"`

If you need double qutoes within the result string, you need to double them.
It's sometimes tricky to find out, what's the right number of quotes ...

Furthermore you should put single quotes around the sheetname variable - as you need them if there is e.g.
a space in the name ...

Comment: the solution worked great, but can I ask you something else?, is it possible to do the same formula but just specify the sheet number like, Sheets(1)? im trying to set a hyperlink back to the main sheet and its not quite jiving

Comment: You can use `thisworkbook.worksheets(1).name` instead of the variables name

Comment: seriously can't thank you enough, that Hyperlink Syntax was driving me insane